# how to retain the drop down value using 'selected' attribute after submitting the html form which is within the servlet class itself

Tags: html, servlets, html-select

public class ServletApplication extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    int number1 , number2, number3;
    /*
     * Setting the content type to html
     */
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    /*
     * Getting the printWriter object
     */
    PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();
    /*
     * Html form in the servlet class itself
     */

    pr.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    pr.println("<html>");
    pr.println("<head>");
    pr.println("<tittle>CALCULATOR</tittle");
    pr.println("</head>");
    pr.println("<body>");
    pr.println("<form action = 'ServletApplication' method = 'Get'>");
    /*
     * Retain the values that are entered 
     */
    String n1 = request.getParameter("number1") != null?request.getParameter("number1"):"";
    String n2 = request.getParameter("number2") != null?request.getParameter("number2"):"";
    pr.println("<br>number1:<input type='text' name= 'number1' value="+n1+" ><br>");
    pr.println("<br>number2:<input type='text' name= 'number2' value="+n2+" ><br><br>");
    pr.println("operation:<select name='options'>");
    pr.println("<option name='add' >add</option>");
    pr.println("<option name='multiply' >multiply</option>"); 
    pr.println("<option name='subtract'  >subtract</option>");
    pr.println("<option name='divide' >divide</option>");
    pr.println("</select><br><br>");
    pr.println("<button type= 'submit' value = 'process' name = 'button'>process</button> ");
    pr.println("<button type= 'submit' value = 'cancel' name = 'button'>cancel</button> ");
    pr.println("</form>");
    pr.println("</body>");
    pr.println("</html>");
    /*
     * Avoiding the null format exception
     */
    if (request.getParameter("number2") != null) 
    {

        String button = request.getParameter("button");
        if (button.equals("process")) {
            number1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number1"));
            number2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number2"));
            String select = request.getParameter("options");

            /*
             * Switch case to select from the drop-down
             */
            switch (select) {
            case "add":
                number3 = number1 + number2;
                pr.println("<br>result:<input type = 'text' value =" + number3 + " />");
                break;
            case "multiply":
                number3 = number1 * number2;
                pr.println("<br>result:<input type = 'text' value =" + number3 + " />");
                break;
            case "divide":
                try
                {
                number3 = number1 / number2;
                pr.println("<br>result:<input type = 'text' value =" + number3 + " />");
                }
                catch(ArithmeticException e)
                {
                    pr.println("<br>result:<input type = 'text' value ='cant divide by zero' />");

                }
                break;
            case "subtract":
                number3 = number1 - number2;
                pr.println("<br>result:<input type = 'text' value =" + number3 + " />");
                break;

            }       

        }

        else 
            response.sendRedirect("ServletApplication");

    }


}
```

}

how can i retain the value of the drop down after submitting the form, everything is done in this servlet class alone, am not using an html file or jsp or anything. i want to run this in the servlet class itself. i don't want to use jsp or javaScript or php. i have tried using ternary if within the println statement but its not working , please help

Comment: How about a local variable as the 'selected' option and when creating the form you take its value as the selected (default would be none) but after submitting that variable will be the previous options. Then have a separate setting for resetting where you run the same logic that creates the form in the first place and do not call the reset on that form.

Comment: @SebastianG i have seen in jsp and js, they just do with an if condition. can we apply the same  here? am not able to. Am new to servlet and html tags

Comment: hey, i got the answer, i could use a ternary if within that line itself , its working.
Thanks anyways!